# Power Series Expansion of $z-1$ at $(0,0,1) \in S^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A = \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$ the coordinate ring of the sphere $S^2 = \{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{A}^3_{\mathbb{C}} \mid a^2+b^2+c^2=1 \}$, and $\mathfrak{m} = (x,y,z-1)$ the maximal ideal of $A$ generated by $x,y,z-1$. We can choose $x,y$ as local parameters at $p=(0,0,1)$. I want to write the Taylor Series expansion (see Shafarevich - Basic Algebraic Geometry 2.2.2) of $z-1 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P_k(x,y)$ at $p$ using $x,y$ as local parameters (thus $P_k \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ are homogeneous polynomials such that $z-1 - \sum_{k=0}^n P_k(x,y) \in \mathfrak{m}^{n}$).

We have that $z-1 \in \mathfrak{m}$, thus $P_0=0$. However, I'm stuck trying to find $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $z-1 -a x - b y \in \mathfrak{m}^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using
$$(z - 1) = \frac{z^2 - 1}{2} - \frac{(z - 1)^2}{2} = \frac{-x^2-y^2-(z - 1)^2}{2}$$
we have $(z - 1) \in \mathfrak{m}^2$, so $a = b = 0$ suffice.

Comment: Could you help me write its Taylor Series expansion at $(0,0,1)$ using $x,y$ as local paratemers?

Comment: You can do this by noting that $$z - 1 = \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2} - 1$$ and use the Taylor series for sqrt.